# Seeking into a specific function in gdb

Tags: gdb, reverse-engineering, radare2

While doing reverse engineering i always need to seek into specific functions. I used to work with `radare2` with the command `s <function_name>`, which set a breakpoint on the first instruction of `function_name`.

Is there a similar method in gdb?

Comment: What does the `s <function name>` _do_?

Comment: @EmployedRussian it makes a breakpoint in the first instruction of <function name>

Comment: Interesting.  Is the radare2 different to the one here: https://book.rada.re/first_steps/intro.html ?  As the seek command of that tool does not create breakpoints.  At least according to the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a similar method in gdb?

Yes: `break *function_name`.

From `(gdb) help break`:

```
Address locations begin with "*" and specify an exact address in the
program.  Example: To specify the fourth byte past the start function
"main", use "*main + 4".
```